# Why do I have to reset my password every single time I log in? (It says my password is wrong.)

Tags: support, user-interface, login

[image]

Every time I try to log in it says the password is wrong, so my only choice is to reset it.

I'm using my e-mail address and password, not an OAuth provider.

Why do I have to reset my password every single time I log in? This has happened 3 times in a row over 3 weeks.

I reset the password using the e-mail link. Then I'm in, but just for a while.

I am not using a password manager.  I keep my passwords in a file I maintain. There is no space after the password.

Comment: I tried logging in with an incorrect password on purpose and I don't see a link that says "reset your password" (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/fygIM.png). Perhaps you  meant that you clicked "Forgot password?"? Either way, I suggest going to the contact page and submitting the contact form. Maybe something is off with your account: https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: Do you have to reset your password every single time you try to log in? If so, I would suggest making a very simple password that passes the minimum password requirements, log out, then log back in and type it in manually to eliminate variables associated with copying from a text document. On the other hand, if you can log in successfully sometimes, and sometimes not, that could mean your computer is compromised.

Comment: @CaveJohnson OP didn't say there is link to reset password, but rather doing it manually as the password is wrong. We can't know why, but it's not something on SE side.

Comment: @Kyle I suspect the issue is with the way you copy and paste the password from the file. If you're using some software for opening that file, copying might also copy special characters which aren't visible, but visible to the server when pasting, making it wrong. Try to open the file in Notepad or other plain editor and copy from there.

Comment: Did you log in using a Stack Exchange account (email & password) or OAuth providers (Google, Facebook)? Where did you get the wrong password on?

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard In the third paragraph they explicitly said they clicked a link that says 'reset your password' (with quotes). I'm guessing they meant 'Forgot password' as that also allows you to reset your password. I'm not sure what is the distinction between clicking a link to reset your password and doing it manually.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard  Yes.  When a login says your password is wrong, you go through the reset procedure.  I've done that 3 times in two weeks.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT.  I'm using an e-mail address and password. It says my password is wrong, so I click on forgot password and use the reset password link.  I've done this 3 times in two weeks.

Comment: From all the comments here, it's clear that your case is more complicated than we can handle as community volunteers. It's definitely something you need to resolve via the [Contact Us](/contact) form, as has been suggested.

Comment: @rene  I updated the picture. Sorry, when I made that picture I just put in garbage.  I was already logged in, so I made the screens I see in a private browsing window (rather than logging out as possibly dealing with this issue again).

Comment: Well, my previous comment still stands, and so far ignored. If using complex editor to copy and paste, it might add special characters. In such case, everything else is totally not relevant.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard I already tested that the paste contains just text (actually long ago, and I again verified it).  This problem hasn't happened anywhere else.

Comment: @Kyle Did you try my suggestion of resetting your password, then manually typing out your password character by character? Just to help narrow down the issue. I mean it still could be something with SE, your browser, or something else. But at least we would know whether it's associated with copying passwords.

Comment: @CaveJohnson  The next time this happens I will try manually typing in my password.  I'll need to go inactive a couple days, clear my cache and cookies, for this to repeat again, based on past results.

Comment: @Kyle Can you not just reset your password now and log out, to test it?

Comment: No.  It will probably just work.

Comment: @Kyle If you are sometimes able to log in, and sometimes not, I'm perplexed. I think it's best to just contact SE here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: @CaveJohnson  I just tested this, and the problem happened.  --  Logout (on all sites).  Clear cache and cookies. Login to stats.stackexchange.com -- password is incorrect.  Reset password.  Follow link in email, set password, and I'm back in.  I didn't go through a log-in screen.

Comment: @Kyle So you manually typed in your password this time?

Comment: @CaveJohnson  I tried it both ways. Pasting to a text file to confirm it's clean, and pasting it in the form, and just manually typing it in the form.

Comment: The reply (auto) from meta.stackexchange.com/contact  is totally useless.  "You can use any of the following credentials  (my e-mail address.)" Once logged in, you can review existing credentials and add new ones."  There's nothing else in the e-mail, except a reset password link.  ---  I used the "other" option in the contact form, as nothing was applicable.

Comment: I got a reply from a real person at meta.stackexchange.com/contact.  I will post an answer here when this issue is resolved.

Comment: The real person has not replied. I'll keep waiting.

Comment: @Kyle is this a Gmail account? If so use the login with Gmail and don't use the manual email address. I have these problems also. Lots of sites let you login now with your Gmail credentials and it creates an account for you

Comment: No, it's not gmail.